# Why use the plural form of feeling?

Tags: meaning, definition

> But I always managed to forget my **guilty** **feelings** every time we sat down to plan our next month's adventure. And I haven't changed...

A particular type of feeling is always used with "a singular feeling" as in **guilty feeling** and **feelings** are the general emotions we feel (mentioned in Lexicon dictionary).

So why the author has used the plural form here?

Comment: Please provide either a link to the place where you saw this text, or a précis of the things that happened before this passage. Without that, we can't say whether or not this is a legitimate usage of the plural.

Comment: Harry Potter and the Prisoner of azkaban chapter 18

Comment: that tells me absolutely nothing about what happened before this particular passage. Please provide a summary of what happened. And please edit your question  using the **Edit** keyword below the question, rather than adding details in comments.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel guilty about something, you have a single feeling of guilt- a guilty feeling.

If you have a number of feelings that you think you should not have, they are guilty feelings - plural. This is analogous to the expression "guilty secrets", where you have more than one secret that you feel guilty about.

If you regularly feel guilty about something, they are multiple instances of the same feeling, so they are guilty feelings - plural.

I can't comment on the passage that you quoted because you didn't provide a link, so I will make up a story  of my own.

Let's say he doesn't like his boss, because 1) He feels that his boss doesn't appreciate his work. 2) he feels that his boss is stupid, 3) He feels that his boss is impolite.... etc. Each of these is a separate feeling, so he has **feelings** (plural) about his boss. He thinks that he should not have these feelings, so they are guilty feelings - plural.

Comment: Do you mean he felt that way at several instances, that's why "guilty feelings "?

Comment: Sometimes guilty feelings are feeling that you should have - if I robbed an old blind woman, I hope I would have very guilty feelings.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey what would these guilty feelings be: 1) I feel guilty 2) I feel guilty 3)I feel guilty....

Comment: I would reasonably call recurring pangs of guilt 'feelings'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey fair comment.

Comment: I also think that if I met my new sweetheart at a romantic spot, and said 'I have amorous feelings for you', and she said 'Really? Enumerate them!', I might well have to stop and think for a bit.

Comment: No - "guilty feelings" is far more likely to mean "multiple instances of feeling guilty (possibly at the same time)" than "feelings about which one does or should feel guilty".

Comment: @psmears bear in mind that in the expression "guilty secrets", we are talking about more than one secret that makes us feel guilty. We are not talking about multiple instances of feeling guilty about one thing.

Comment: @JavaLatte: Right. But that's a particular fixed phrase. It doesn't mean the word "guilty" always works like that - e.g. the phrase "guilty prisoners" doesn't mean that we should feel guilty that they're prisoners, it means the prisoners are guilty of something. Moreover phrases like "sad feelings", "happy feelings" etc. refer to feelings of sadness, happiness, rather than feelings about which we'd feel sad, happy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most direct reading of "feeling" vs "feelings" is that the plural form indicates either feelings that regularly surface, or feelings that can't be defined simply (as in, it's not just guilt, it's also envy, and maybe some lust, there's always some of that lingering).

Answer (score 1):

Guilt is a complex feeling, and it rarely consists of just one "feeling".  Let's say I stole a something from a store.  I might feel:

1. Guilty that I broke the law.
2. Guilty that I disappointed my parents.
3. Guilty that I went against the precepts of my religion.
4. Guilty that I stole something after previously having decided I would never do something like that.

And so on, and so forth.  These are all multiple feelings, they are all guilty feelings, and I have them all.

There are other feelings that have a similar complex nature, and are similarly pluralized.  For example, I could say that I have romantic feelings to someone:

1. I am physically attracted to their appearance.
2. I appreciate the things they've done.
3. I like their personality.
4. I want to spend time with them.
5. I want to have sex.

And so on.  A lot more complicated than the simple situation of, "It's a nice day, I feel happy."  On the other hand, I might have "feeling***s*** of happiness" if the nice day reminded me of better times, making the feeling much more complicated than simple happiness.

Oftentimes, the emotions are *so* complicated and tangled that a person will not necessarily be able to articulate the exact feelings they are having in lists like I have provided here, but you can still feel inside yourself that it isn't just one simple feeling, but a whole bunch all mixed together.  In these cases, we use the plural.